# How to change default alarm sound?

Tags: 8.1, notifications, alarms, sound

I'm using Windows Phone 8.1 on a Nokia 920. I can create new alarms no problem. But the default sound for those alarms is not the one I'd prefer (it's using Nokia Clock which is too quiet for me). How do I change the default for new alarms to something like Alarm 6?

BTW, while I can change it manually easily enough, if I set the alarm using Cortana then it uses the default sound and to fix it I have to go to Alarm app to do it which makes Cortana much less helpful.

Comment: I never run into this problem, I've always used the default *default sound* :) But now I know this it will bug me :D

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue too, but there is a work-around. You can set a series of alarms for the times you need with the alarm 6 tone (the only one that wakes me up!). Then Cortana can switch those alarms on (eg: say "Turn on my 6.00am alarm").

Answer (score 1):

Yep just change it in each alarm, once.    so if you save wake me up at 2PM, and a PM alarm is already there and set to Nostalgia.. then it will be fine.

But its a deficiency, someone please add it to wishlist for windows 10.
https://windows.uservoice.com/

they should always allow default setting on the same page,  or use the last set as default.. that is standard UI.

if you say "Wake me up in 45 minutes"... you'd have probably have to change it.  but its accessible on the Cortana screen after it sets it.

my friends with other phones block whats app and mess with volumes...Quiet Hours is an excellent feature.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about Settings Alarm through Cortana. There is no way I've heard of to get Cortana to use any other ringtone for the alarm but the default. Maybe later down the road with the official upgrade, but wouldn't hold my breath for it.

I would prefer to set an alarm manually. It just takes around 10 secs :) ;)

Comment: Surprisingly, Cortana's actually pretty handy for setting alarms and reminders. I'm not sure I find the other Cortana features useful yet, but alarms and reminders are fast and convenient.

Comment: Yes I do agree to that.! Its quiet convenient and fun to say "Wake me up at 7 a.m.". :D But then the alarm tone sets to default. :( That is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have Czech T-Mobile SIM card and I was quite satisfied with default alarm tone, but after inserting this SIM card default tone changed. The point is that now it is too loud. (I guess it would wake up even a dead person now.)

So that might be a solution for you-switching a phone on once with T-Mobile SIM card.